# Converting an s3 bucket policy to base64 from JSON in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, base64

I'm trying to encode an Amazon s3 bucket policy in base64 in node.js for the signature (more specifically the StringToSign), but can't seem to get the code right.

I'm using a default policy provided by amazon to test with because they provide the correct base64 encoding. ([The example given by amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html))

Their output is `eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDE1........` (Keeping it short because it's quite long)

I keep getting `eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMi0zMFQx.....`

my code to generate this is:

```
var policyString = JSON.stringify(policy)
var policyBytes = utf8.encode(policyString)
var stringToSign = base64.encode(policyBytes)
```

where `policy` is a variable holding the amazon policy in JSON format, and `utf8` and `base64` are node modules.

This might sound like a novice question but I've been staring at it for awhile now and any hlep would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a full output of your base64 encoded value

Comment: If I understand correctly, the the aws sdk provides this functionality: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property
you can check the source code for details on how they calculate it: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/d3f0701e8aff9697231f023d2e5a5c289a8ec8ec/lib/services/s3.js#L905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decoded the current partial values you have provided

```
eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDE1
eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMi0zMFQx
```

Respective outputs were:

```
{ "expiration": "2015
{"expiration":"2015-12-30T1
```

As you can see, in your `policyString` you have removed some spaces. This is the reason for you to get a different output

Comment: This was it! It was caused by JSON.stringify(). I instead put the policy on one line and surrounded it with single quotes.

Comment: Great. Apart accepting the answer, if it helps, upvoting would send some love :)

Comment: @blongo What do you mean you put the policy on one line and surrounded it with single quotes? Can you be more specific? Are you saying that you make the object a string by surrounding it in single quotes?

Like... Buffer.from('${obj_here}').toString('base64')